# FileDropTarget Drag and Drop doesn't work on macOS

Tags: wxpython, apple-m1

I was interested in playing with binaural audio, and I found out this work on GitHub: https://github.com/aechoi/hrtfmixer.git

I have never used wxpython before, and I don't understand why Drag and Drop doesn't work. I can get the frame to open. Maybe wxpython doesn't work properly on my M1 mac?
When I drag and drop the file onto the text box, it "rejects" the file.
[image: Drag and Drop doesn't work]

```
import wx

app = wx.App(False)


########################################################################
class MyFileDropTarget(wx.FileDropTarget):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, window):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.FileDropTarget.__init__(self)
        self.window = window
        self.fileNames = []

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def OnDropFiles(self, x, y, filenames):
        """
        When files are dropped, write where they were dropped and then
        the file paths themselves
        """
        self.window.SetInsertionPointEnd()
        # self.window.updateText("\n%d file(s) dropped at %d,%d:\n" %
        #                       (len(filenames), x, y))
        for filepath in filenames:
            self.window.updateText('Loaded ' + filepath.split('\\')[-1] + '\n')    
        # print (filenames)
        # return filenames
        self.fileNames = filenames
        frame.Close()
        return True

########################################################################
class DnDPanel(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)

        self.file_drop_target = MyFileDropTarget(self)
        lbl = wx.StaticText(self, label="Drag a 16-bit .wav file here.\nThe modified file will be saved in the same location.")
        self.fileTextCtrl = wx.TextCtrl(self,
                                        style=wx.TE_MULTILINE|wx.HSCROLL|wx.TE_READONLY)
        self.fileTextCtrl.SetDropTarget(self.file_drop_target)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(lbl, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        sizer.Add(self.fileTextCtrl, 1, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 5)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def SetInsertionPointEnd(self):
        """
        Put insertion point at end of text control to prevent overwriting
        """
        self.fileTextCtrl.SetInsertionPointEnd()

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def updateText(self, text):
        """
        Write text to the text control
        """
        self.fileTextCtrl.WriteText(text)

########################################################################
class DnDFrame(wx.Frame):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent=None, title='Select a File')
        self.panel = DnDPanel(self)
        self.Show()

#########################################################################
frame = DnDFrame()
class dragStarter():
    def __init__(self):
        app.MainLoop()
        self.fileName = frame.panel.file_drop_target.fileNames
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__.endswith("__main__"):
    # app = wx.App(False)
    # frame = DnDFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
    print(frame.panel.file_drop_target.fileNames)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like old code and whilst it does work, sort of, it closes as soon as a file is dropped.
If you are not running this from the command line, you may think, nothing is happening.
Try this instead (Drop file/s in the Top Box):

```
import wx

import wx.lib.newevent
drop_event, EVT_DROP_EVENT = wx.lib.newevent.NewEvent()

class MyFileDropTarget(wx.FileDropTarget):
    def __init__(self, obj):
        wx.FileDropTarget.__init__(self)
        self.obj = obj

    def OnDropFiles(self, x, y, filename):
        #filename is a list of 1 or more files
        #here we are restricting it 1 file by only taking the first item of the list
        TempTxt = filename
        evt = drop_event(data=TempTxt)
        wx.PostEvent(self.obj,evt)

        return True


class Example(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        super(Example, self).__init__(parent, title=title)
        self.InitUI()
        self.Center()

    def InitUI(self):
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        FileDrTr = MyFileDropTarget(self)
        TextLabel = wx.StaticText(panel, label = 'Drop file/s here')
        self.NewText = wx.TextCtrl(panel, value = 'Files display here\n', style=wx.TE_MULTILINE|wx.HSCROLL|wx.TE_READONLY)

        Drop_Place = wx.TextCtrl(panel)
        Drop_Place.SetDropTarget(FileDrTr)

        #Bind the drop event listener
        self.Bind(EVT_DROP_EVENT, self.LabelTextUpdate)

        verBox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        horBoxOne = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        horBoxOne.Add(TextLabel, flag=wx.RIGHT, border=10)
        horBoxOne.Add(Drop_Place, proportion=1)

        horBoxTwo = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        horBoxTwo.Add(self.NewText, proportion=1, flag=wx.EXPAND)

        verBox.Add(horBoxOne, flag=wx.EXPAND, border=20)
        verBox.Add((-1, 10))
        verBox.Add(horBoxTwo, proportion=1, flag=wx.EXPAND, border=20)
        panel.SetSizer(verBox)
        self.Show()

    def LabelTextUpdate(self, event):
        self.NewText.Clear()
        text = event.data
        for txt in text:
            self.NewText.write(txt+'\n')


def main():
    app = wx.App()
    ex = Example(None, title = 'drop and see file path')
    app.MainLoop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image]
It works on Linux